# How can we resample the buffer received in onDataAvailable event

Tags: audio, naudio

I need to resample the buffer(to (16 kHz 16-bit mono PCM) received in onDataAvaiable event of mic and speaker and then pass the stream to another application. How can this be achieved using nAudio?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my article on "[input driven resampling](http://markheath.net/post/input-driven-resampling-with-naudio-using-acm)" with NAudio where I explain how you can pass the incoming audio from the soundcard to a resampler

Comment: Thanks mark, If I understand correctly ACM resampler won’t change bit depths or channel counts at the same time. In my case I need to change the bit depth and channel count as well.

Comment: yes, you'd do that as a separate step, or use the MediaFoundationResampler which is more flexible

Comment: Mark, MediaFoundationResampler expects an IWaveProvider , is there a way I can pass a buffer to it ? I haven't worked with audio related things before. If you could point me to an example that would be great.

Comment: unfortunately, I've not yet done the work to easily support input driven resampling with MediaFoundationResampler.